# For loop runs half for any count

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I"m trying to count the # of successful outcomes of running a certain test, which has only 2 outcomes, success or failure (code for test is not given below). 
I need a loop that runs the test for 20 times and prints out the rate of success out of 20 times.
I don't know why but my loop only prints an output only 10 times! This always is the case. When I change the ending condition to any number other than 20, it only prints runs for half of that number.

Attached is only the relevant pieces of the code. Is there something wrong with the logic? I couldn't find it.

```
 double successRate = 0; //initialize variable recording total times of successes of test
  for (int count = 1; count <= 20; count++)
    {
        string result = sf(fliptest()); //result of running the test the first time, only equals one of two strings: "success" or "failure"
        if (result =="success")
        {
            successRate++;
            cout << result << endl;
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << result << endl;
            count++;
        }
    }
 cout << "The % of success is" << (successRate/20)*100 << " %" << endl;
```

Comment: because you do count++ twice.  if you want count++), then get rid of these: count++;

Comment: You increment `count` twice per iteration. Once in the for loop statement, and one in the loop body.

Comment: Your `for-loop` is incrementing the count. Then you increment it again in the body of the `for-loop`. In other words every iteration of the loop increments the count **twice**. Therefore the loop encounters the stopping condition with half the iterations.

Comment: Oh my goodness. You're right! I think I'm too bleary eyed to notice :D!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are incrementing your count variable in your for statement and in your if else blocks, either remove the count++ from the for loop or from your if else blocks.

this should work:

```
double successRate = 0; //initialize variable recording total times of successes of test
for (int count = 1; count <= 20; count++)
{
    string result = sf(fliptest()); //result of running the test the first time, only equals one of two strings: "success" or "failure"
    if (result =="success")
    {
        successRate++;
        cout << result << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << result << endl;
    }
}
cout << "The % of success is" << (successRate/20)*100 << " %" << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove count++ in if and else condition. It will increase the count value again so it gets double and your getting output for half of the 20 times.

Answer (score 0):

The no. of times your for-loop should run is reduced to half since you are incrementing "count" twice, once in the for-statement and once in the body of the for-statement. Removing one of the two will fix the issue.